# Instalación de PHP en Uubntu 18.04 server ... Fallo en la instalación de extensiones

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

Estoy en Uubntu Server 18.04.1, queriendo instalar la versión última 7.2.10 de PHP

Al ejecutar los comando básicos de `sudo apt-get install php php-pear php-fpm php-dev php-zip php-curl php-xmlrpc php-gd php-mysql php-mbstring php-xml libapache2-mod-php` parece que la instalación no termina de tener lugar.

Así que me ha dado por añadir un repositorio desde el que se puede descargar la última versión de PHP:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php.
sudo apt-get update
```

Luego, hago la instalación de PHP 7.2

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2 php-pear php7.2-curl php7.2-dev php7.2-gd php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml
```

Entonces, es cuando empiezan a saltarme errores debido a dependencias previas que necesitan algunas de las extensiones que pretendo instalar, concretamene la `php7.2-mbstring` y la `php7.2-zip` que según parece deenden de una versión de php7.2-common anterior a la ya instalada con el comando anterior (si ya está instalada la versión 7.2.10, las dependencias de mbtring y zip piden la 7.2.9) Como no exiten las versiones de dependencias previas las dos extensiones mencionadas no se terminan de instalar.

Aparte la de php7.2-zip tambien depende de la dependencia libzip4 que tampoco llego a instalar.

Finalmente, llego a este **[sitio](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+sourcepub/9343812/+listing-archive-extra)** del que descargo las versiones php7.2-common_7.2.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb y la php7.2-mbstring_7.2.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb y las instalo por la terminal a través de "sudo dpkg -i" Pero para poder instalar esta versión del common, debo desinstalar la ya instalada más actual, la 7.2.10 pero entonces, las otras extensiones ya instaladas que dependen de esta 7.2.10 se quejana a su vez y el sistema recomienda aplicar `sudo apt --fix-broken install` lo que desinstala la vesión 7.2.9 de php-common para instalar la 7.2.10 y asu vez la php7.2-mbstring que termine logrando instalar, lo mismo para la php7.2-zip.

Y entonces vuelvo al punto de partida en el que no tengo o no puedo instalar la extensión php7.2-mbstring porque me vuelve a pedir tener instalada la dependencia php7.2-common en su versión 7.2.9 y no la 7.2.10 que necesitan las otras extensiones menos la de php7.2-zip que además necesita libzip4 v.1.0 ... y etc, etc,...

¿Cómo puedo salir de este bucle y tener instalado correctamente PHP 7.2 en su última versión con las extensiones necesarias, entre ellas, la de php-mbstring y php-zip que son necesarias para instalar Composer, por ejemplo?

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar a solucionar esto sin tener que volver a reinstalar la máquina virtual desde cero?

---

EDICIÓN

Revisando el **[enlace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062160/package-php7-2-mbstring-unmet-dependencies-in-ubuntu-18-04)** propuesto por @Xerif, se aplica la respuesta aceptada del post y, con ello, se solucionó el problema que planteaba en mi pregunta.

En resumen, la cuestión está en el archivo `/etc/apt/sources.list` que, en su contenido de origen, está así (para ver su contenido, `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

Esto hace que ciertos canales de actualizaciones se pierdan.
Para que esto no suceda, el contenido del archivo debe quedar de esa forma:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main multiverse restricted universe
```

Tras guardar los cambios en el archivo, se lanza el comando de actualización:

```
sudo apt update
```

Y ya solo queda instalar el módulo que se desee, por ejemplo:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-mbstring
```

Eso es todo.

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062160/package-php7-2-mbstring-unmet-dependencies-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Gracias, funcionó la solución propuesta en la respuesta elegida del post sugerido. Añado las líneas sugeridas para solucionar la cuestión editando mi pregunta. ... Saludos.

Comment: En lugar de editar la pregunta es mejor que lo añadas como respuesta y la marque como solucionada. Aun que seas el creador de la pregunta tambien puedes autoresponderte, Un saludo